Jupyter does not release a numpy memmap file handle
When creating a numpy memory mapped file in a Jupyter notebook, I find the following works, but additional writes in later cells fail because the file handle is still being held. Specifically the error is
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'filename'
But I know it's a resource management issue because when I try to delete the file from the terminal I get a resource busy error. When I restart the kernel the issue is resolved until the next write.
arr = np.memmap('array.dat', shape, dtype, mode='w+')
rand = np.random(shape)
arr = rand
arr.flush()

I figured it had to do with the way that Jupyter handles kernels in a session so I wrote a simple wrapper to turn the array into a resource so I could do something like
with MemmapResource('array.dat', shape, mode='w+') as arr:
    rand = np.random(shape)
    arr = rand

But additional writes fail with the same error. The resource wrapper is below.
class MemmapResource:
    def __init__(self, filename, shape, mode='r+', dtype='float32'):
        """
        A context manager for working with memory-mapped numpy arrays.
        
        Parameters:
        - filename: Path to the memory-mapped file.
        - shape: Shape of the memory-mapped array.
        - mode: File access mode ('r+', 'w+', etc.).
        - dtype: Data type of the array.
        """
        self.array = None
        self.filename = filename
        self.shape = shape
        self.mode = mode
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.file = None

    def __enter__(self):
        # Open file based on the mode
        mode = self.mode + '+' if self.mode in ('r', 'w') else self.mode
        if self.mode in ('w+', 'w'):
            self.file = open(self.filename, 'wb+')
        elif self.mode in ('r', 'r+'):
            self.file = open(self.filename, 'rb+')
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported mode {self.mode}")

        # Create the memory-mapped array
        self.array = np.memmap(self.file, dtype=self.dtype, mode=mode, shape=self.shape)
        return self.array

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Flush changes and close the file
        if self.array is not None:
            self.array.flush()
            del self.array  # Ensure the array is deleted to release the memory map
        
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.close()

